# Information extraction. Counting mentions to measure relevance

Tags: nlp, information-extraction, named-entity-recognition

Is it possible to count how many times an entity has been mentioned in an article? For example

> **`ABC Company`** is one of the largest car manufacturers in the
>   world. **`It`** is also the largest
>   company in terms of annual production.
>   **`It`** is also the second largest exporter of luxury cars, after XYZ
>   company. Both **`ABC`** and XYZ
>   together produces over n% of total car
>   production in the country.

mentions ABC company 4 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. It's a combination of

- named-entity recognition (NER), which for English is practically a [solved problem](http://nlp.stanford.edu/ner/index.shtml), and
- coreference resolution, which is the subject of ongoing research (but give [this package](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/18) a try)

Comment: my genuine apologies -- I had typed "where I work", but in revising my text I inadvertently edited out this portion, it seems. You'll see in my other answers I'm consistent about this. (I will remove this comment shortly)

Comment: @John: the -9 you got was a bit harsh. I didn't expect that, but neither can I take full responsibility for it. No hard feelings from me, just watch out when editing your posts :)